# Show Pads with their Name on PCB altium

Tags: altium

I have imported a schematic in PCB and placed components. But one thing is missing, its not showing pads names as they are appearing in schematic. It can only show Designator and Comments of component in PCB but not the pads name.

How can I make them appear ?

Thank you

Added screenshot, how to do like this. Like 1 appearing next to pin 1, 2 appearing next to pin 2. But when I add a header, nothing appears, only the entire component designator appears.

[image: screen]

Answer (score 2):

If you want something to be shown on the silkscreen, you basically have two options:

- If you want it to be reusable, add the text to the PCB library item (the underlying footprint). The correct layer is named "Top Overlay". This is typically your silkscreen and it's also the only layer which can be displayed in the 3D view as "silkscreen".
- If you want it just for this one project, just add some text to your PCB (again, on the Top Overlay layer)

One more thing: You cannot add that kind of numbering automatically (well, maybe you could with a script, but this will include some work).

Comment: That is very basic thing, I wish it was added in default library :(

Comment: Hm .. To be honest, I do not agree. In fact it's quite unusual on a print with more parts. Usually it's enough to designate Pin 1 or similar

Comment: It is very usual for headers to know what a pin is for. And it is super useful and saves time by avoiding to keep matching pins with the board manual. Like arduino, netduino, I2C interface and many others. I usually see them marked for each pin. :)

Comment: Those are development boards and therefore intended for development where you need that info. With a normal product, the only thing you need is the name/number of the connector. If you can insert the connector in at least two different orientiations you will also need to mark that. but no need to describe every pin.

Comment: So altium is not for development boards ? besides people also need pins info for normal products too.

Comment: Sure, as you see you can do it. Altium just won't do it for you.

Comment: True, the screenshot in question post is from altium official website :) I like altium, its very easy but it doesn't have a proper inbuilt library. Even very common components are missing or lack features.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:  The numbers near the header are added in the Footprint.  They are on the silkscreen layer.

Are you trying to show the net names connected to the Pads?  If so, that is done in the View Configurations dialog (Design » Board Layers and Colors).

[Check out this Altium tutorial](http://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADOH/Tutorial+-+Getting+Started+with+PCB+Design) and search for "Show Pad Nets"

Comment: Not net name but I want it to show the pad names. Like a 3 pin header, should show Pin1, Pin2, Pin3 along with the pins.

Comment: Added a screenshot

Comment: @xmenW.K.: are you talking about the silkscreen, or something to only appear while doing design? Your picture isn't clear whether that's what you see and you are missing something, or if that's what you want to see and something is missing, etc.

Comment: @xmenW.K., you need to edit your pcb (or integrated) library to add the numbers to each footprint.

Comment: I need to show pad names on Silkscreen, so it will be printed after pcb is done. It is for marking each pin, what a pin is for. Like pin1 is "GND", pin2 is "VCC".

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the labels manually. It is not useful to mark the chips pins because you can look it up on your schematic. You normally just name the pins which go off the board (when using 2.54mm Header) and add description to status leds.

But automatically name each pin would take too much space for products in the industry. If you want to make a pcb for your own for development reasons and you have a dip ic on your board it may make sense but not in other cases