# Show Pad Nets Seemingly Not Working in Altium

Tags: pcb, altium

For some reason, the PCB is not showing net names on the pads

I have all connections (rats nests) visible
I have checked the "Show Pad Nets" and "Show Via Nets" under the View Configurations > View Options Panel

I have checked layer colors and everything is on

What other setting might there be which is preventing the net names from displaying within the pads/vias on the PCB layout?

I am running AD15 on Windows 8.1 and this is really bugging me!

This is an example screen shot of the PCB environment, you can see that despite the option for "show pad nets" being enabled, they are not showing.
[image]

Thanks for the help

This question is not the same as another related question "Show Pads with their Name on PCB altium " which discussed adding silkscreen designators. It is about why the Altium feature "show pad nets" does not seem to be working to show the 'virtual' net names in the PCB tool within the pads

Comment: I answered that very question in the post you obviously saw. Although it's older, the information in there is still true: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/154605/show-pads-with-their-name-on-pcb-altium

Comment: Actually you did not answer my question. Your post over there related to silkscreen which is NOT my question. Someone else linked to the Altium info about "Show Pad Nets" but that is NOT working for me, which is why I made this post. Thanks

Comment: I see ... when you double-click a net, is the correct net name assigned to that net?

Comment: That thread does not answer my question, it is not a duplicate

Comment: Sorry for the delay, adding comments does not trigger an email to me.  Yes, there are no issues with the nets having the correct name, it is only that the net names (or pin numbers for that matter) are not displayed in the PCB Environment within the copper objects.

Comment: Three ideas: #1: Reset your preferences; #2: Create a new PCB, load your data into that PCB (that way you should see if your layer options (Key:L) are somewhat off)

Comment: I have tried both of these and the result is the same. Still cannot see net names on pads or tracks, even when making them partially transparent.   What is the third idea?   And why is my post being flagged as a duplicate by 5 moderators when it is clearly not? This is preventing visibility from someone that might be able to help me.

Comment: Sorry, third one obviously didn't make it ... #3: Try creating a new Project with a new PCB doc - transfer some nets to the PCB - do they show up correctly? I've also read that this may be related to your graphics driver - have you tried updating it? (yes, I know - this seems far fetched). Anyway, you might want to post these issues to the Altium forums (forums.live.altium.com) - maybe somebody else over there has a better idea. Which Version of Altium are you running?

Answer (score 1):

I really don't appreciate several moderators flagging my post as a duplicate even after I explained explicitly and exactly why it is not. This is not a very helpful way to run a forum.

Tom has been the only one trying to help, and I'm grateful.

I was able to get a response from Altium that when running a Virtual Machine there can be compatibility problems with DirectX, which the Show Pad Nets, Show Via Nets, and Show Pad Numbers features all rely on.

The response I received is as follows and I believe answers the question I raised:
"Net Names on tracks and Pads are dependent on Direct X.
Some Virtual machines have problems allowing Altium the usage of Direct X.
You may need to install the windows video card driver for the particular video card you are using inside of the virtual machine with in the windows environment.

If you are not using a Virtual Machine and if your Video Card supports Direct X then possibly re-installing the latest version of the video card driver may resolve the issue"

I hope this helps someone else out in the future.